# Is there a way to use Ricoh1200s printer with OSX?

Tags: macos, printing, driver

The printer only comes with Windows drivers only and is not listed in OSX nor in the Gimp-print list.

I've also tried the generic PCL6 driver (which makes it print black dots to the side of the page but not more.)

any idea?

Comment: Normally any PPD for a similar Ricoh printer should work. I see no 1200s or even 1200 printer listed on the USA website. Can you link to the Ricoh page where the equivalent windows driver is stored?

Comment: http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/rcn/model/sp1200/sp1200cs.htm and http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/re/model/sp12s/sp12sen.htm

Answer (score 1):

Ricoh has a page that links to general printer drivers:

http://ricoh-usa.com/downloads/downloads.aspx?utm_id=18&d=ds

That has a link at the bottom to show that they bundle the PPD and Apple provides the actual drivers to end users.

http://support.apple.com/downloads/Ricoh_Printer_Drivers_for_Mac_OS_X_v10_6

Assuming you didn't get prompted to download the drivers when you added the printer using the System Preferences, you can manually download the driver and try configuring the printer again after deleting the faulty definition from your Mac. Unfortunately, the SP 1200 isn't listed as an explicitly supported printer, so hopefully the official drivers still work. If not, you might need a print server to translate or modify the official drivers.